# Taylor Polynomial of degree 2

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Suppose g is a function which has continuous derivatives, and that$ g(8)=1,g′(8)=−1,g″(8)=−3$, and $g'''(8)=2 $

What is the Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ for $g$ near $8$?

I am relatively new to Taylor series, so it could be the way this question is worded, but I am not sure what the question is asking for. While I have come to this site several time before, this is my first post, so I apologize if I am not following all eligible rules.

Thanks

Comment: Show your work if you want help, did you try anything? do you know what the formula for Taylor series is?

Comment: Amazingly, there is this thing called [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=taylor+polynomial+formula&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=894&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiwyaPTtNTQAhVBPCYKHX33Dq8Q_AUIBigB).  I find one of the top images most useful here, with $x_0=8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The Taylor expansion of a given function $f(x)$ centered in a point $a\in D$, where $D$ is the domain of the function, is given by:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)(x-a)^{n} $$
 Where $f^{(n)}(a)$ is the $n$th derivative at the point of centering.

So I guess if you think what is the degree of a polynomial you can go on.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to adjust for the a in the second part of the series. I was doing Maclaurin series earlier today and forgot that the formula changed when it wasn't centered at 0.